# Is it permitted to sell something to a non-Jew to avoid it becoming muktza?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

The Mishnah Berurah (O.C. 310:12) says that in many cases, items of a non-Jew do not become Muktzah on Shabbos. Is it permitted for one to sell an item of his to a non-Jew before Shabbos, thereby allowing him to move it on Shabbos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The muktzah status for the Jew is because the item was not designated for use on Shabbos and therefore becomes muktzah when Shabbos comes in as the MB says:
שהוא אסור בישראל משום דאתקצאי בין השמשות **ולא הוזמן מבע"י**

*It is forbidden for the Jew because it became muktzah when Shabbos came in and **it had not been designated before Shabbos**.*

Your suggestion is to sell the item to the  non-Jew before Shabbos. Technically this seems fine but practically you could have achieved the same result by designating the item for use on Shabbos and retaining possession.

Other forms of muktzah are not released by being sold to the non-Jew as the MB says:
אבל דבר דאסור בבין השמשות משום מחובר או משום שהיה מחוסר צידה ותלשו הא"י או צדו בשבת אף שהדבר הוא של א"י לכו"ע אסור וכן באיסור נולד ג"כ הכי:

*But something that was forbidden before Shabbos because it was still attached to the ground or had not been trapped and it was detached or trapped by the non-Jew even though it belongs to the non-Jew is still forbidden and similarly for the category of "Nolad" accroding to all opinions.*

Comment: Designating the item for use on Shabbos won't help in cases of Bosis. For example, a candelabra that was lit on a table when Shabbos came in. The Jew cannot pre-designate a lit candle for use on Shabbos. If he sells to a non-jew it would then be permitted.